# Split transactions in a single anchor function

Tags: anchor, transactions, lamports

Let's say I have PDA A, PDA B, and PDA C.
PDA A has lamports. And I like to split lamports to B and C. Is it possible in a single anchor function to transfer lamports from A to B and C?

```
// TRANSACTION 1 (From A to B)
**ctx.accounts.account_b.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_b_lamports
            .checked_add(lamports_to_b)
            .unwrap();

**ctx.accounts.account_a.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_a_lamports
            .checked_sub(lamports_to_b)
            .unwrap();

 // TRANSACTION 2 (From A to C)
**ctx.accounts.account_c.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_c_lamports
            .checked_add(lamports_to_c)
            .unwrap();

**ctx.accounts.account_a.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_a_lamports
            .checked_sub(lamports_to_c)
            .unwrap();
```

Is this possible?
I'm running into a `program error: Error processing Instruction 0`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting up the transaction like this..

```
// TRANSACTION 1 (From A to B)
**ctx.accounts.account_b.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_b_lamports
            .checked_add(lamports_to_b)
            .unwrap();

// TRANSACTION 2 (From A to C)
**ctx.accounts.account_c.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_c_lamports
            .checked_add(lamports_to_c)
            .unwrap();

// SINGLE TRANSFER OUT FROM A
**ctx.accounts.account_a.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = account_a_lamports
            .checked_sub(total_lamports_to_c_and_b)
            .unwrap();
```

I'm not sure the reason why but this ended up working.

Comment: In your first version, `account_a_lamports` changes after the second line to `account_a_lamports - lamports_to_b`, but then you later set it to `account_a_lamports - lamports_to_c`, undoing the deduction of `lamports_to_b` from account a.